# Word for two objects with coplanar axes.

Tags: geometry, definition

Is there a suitable word for describing two objects with coplanar axes (e.g. cylinders)? The word parallel springs to mind, but I wondered if there was anything more specific.

Comment: Is it too long to say "two cylinders with coplanar axes"?

Comment: “Parallel” would not be appropriate if the axes intersect. But just be ready for this: not every mathematical phenomenon has its own name.

Comment: Axicoplanar is not a word, but you could make it one.